# Learning rate adjustment in tensorflow

Tags: python, tensorflow

```
import tensorflow as tf

slim = tf.contrib.slim


def create_learning_rate(curr_step, lr_config):
    base_lr = lr_config.get('base_lr', 0.1)
    decay_steps = lr_config.get('decay_steps', [])
    decay_rate = lr_config.get('decay_rate', 0.1)

    scale_rates = [
        lambda: tf.constant(decay_rate**i, dtype=tf.float32)
        for i in range(len(decay_steps) + 1)
    ]

    conds = []
    prev = -1
    for decay_step in decay_steps:
        conds.append(tf.logical_and(curr_step > prev, curr_step <= decay_step))
        prev = decay_step
    conds.append(curr_step > decay_steps[-1])

    learning_rate_scale = tf.case(
        list(zip(conds, scale_rates)), lambda: 0.0, exclusive=True)
    return learning_rate_scale * base_lr


global_step = slim.create_global_step()
train_op = tf.assign_add(global_step, 1)
lr = create_learning_rate(
    global_step, {"base_lr": 0.1,
                "decay_steps": [10, 20],
                "decay_rate": 0.1})

with tf.Session() as sess:
    init = tf.global_variables_initializer()
    sess.run(init)
    for i in range(30):
        curr_lr, step, _ = sess.run([lr, global_step, train_op])
        print(curr_lr, step)
```

I want to decay the learning rate at certain times. However, it is always 0.001. Any ideas? Or is there a better method to adjust learning rate?

Thanks for your help.

Comment: why not set your learning rate as a placeholder and at each iteration feed any value you want to it?

Comment: Yeah, it's a proper solution too.

Answer (score 0):

It is because lambda function captures variable by reference instead of value.

So the correct manner is

```
def create_learning_rate(global_step, lr_config):
    base_lr = lr_config.get('base_lr', 0.1)
    decay_steps = lr_config.get('decay_steps', [])
    decay_rate = lr_config.get('decay_rate', 0.1)

    prev = -1
    scale_rate = 1.0

    cases = []
    for decay_step in decay_steps:
        cases.append((tf.logical_and(global_step > prev,
                                    global_step <= decay_step),
                    lambda v=scale_rate: v))
        scale_rate *= decay_rate
        prev = decay_step
    cases.append((global_step > decay_step, lambda v=scale_rate: v))
    learning_rate_scale = tf.case(cases, lambda: 0.0, exclusive=True)
    return learning_rate_scale * base_lr
```